# get viewpager text dynamically from mainactivity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-viewpager

i want to give view pager title text from `mainactivity` and save theme in a `ArrayList<String>`

this is my `MainActivity.java`

```
 //======================================================  find tablayout
        TabLayout iTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutMainXml);

        //======================================================  adding tabs to tablayout
        iTabLayout.addTab(iTabLayout.newTab().setText("main"));
        iTabLayout.addTab(iTabLayout.newTab().setText("news"));
        iTabLayout.addTab(iTabLayout.newTab().setText("price"));

        ArrayList<String> tabtitles = new ArrayList<String>();

        tabtitles.add("==> i dont know what am i doing here <== ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is no way for this . finally this is not dynamic but it solved the problem.

```
 //======================================================  find tablayout
        TabLayout iTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutMainXml);

    //======================================================  adding tabs to tablayout
    iTabLayout.addTab(iTabLayout.newTab());
    iTabLayout.addTab(iTabLayout.newTab());
    iTabLayout.addTab(iTabLayout.newTab());

    ArrayList<String> tabtitles = new ArrayList<String>();

    tabtitles.add("main");
    tabtitles.add("top");
    tabtitles.add("news");
```